# Choice of tags on “poll”-related topics

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

Stack Overflow has [poll](/questions/tagged/poll), [polls](/questions/tagged/polls) and [polling](/questions/tagged/polling). These cover several topics:

- Many old “what's your favorite X” questions. These are often tagged [polls](/questions/tagged/polls), and that's the intended meaning of the tag according to its wiki. Hopefully these questions are on their way to deletion, but in the meantime we can't use the tag for something else.
- Questions about gathering answers to multiple-choice questions from many people — making a poll web page in PHP+JS, that kind of stuff. These questions are spread between [poll](/questions/tagged/poll), [polls](/questions/tagged/polls), [polling](/questions/tagged/polling), [survey](/questions/tagged/survey) and quite possible more.
- Questions about concurrency scenarios where a program is waiting for an event. These questions are spread between [poll](/questions/tagged/poll), [polls](/questions/tagged/polls), [polling](/questions/tagged/polling), [survey](/questions/tagged/survey) and quite possible more, including the less-specific [events](/questions/tagged/events).
- The occasional question about the Unix/POSIX `poll` function, drowned in [poll](/questions/tagged/poll).

What would be a good tagging scheme for these topics? We could use [polling](/questions/tagged/polling) for concurrency and [survey](/questions/tagged/survey) for web polls, but I fear that [survey](/questions/tagged/survey) isn't very discoverable. Or we could use [poll](/questions/tagged/poll) for web polls and [polling](/questions/tagged/polling) for concurrency, but such resembling names for completely different tags doesn't work well. Any better suggestions?

Comment: A subset of those could also be retagged to [long-polling]. And there's the tiny (3 Qs) [poller] tag that should probably get cleaned up too once someone finds the best strategy.

Comment: Your question suggests that there needs to be a separate tag for each "polling" concept.  Does there?  Or can we just have a "polling" tag for anything legitimately related to programming polling concepts?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Given that web polls and concurrent programming polls have nothing to do with each other except the name, yes, I think there should be different tags.

Comment: The question is now moot as [tag:poll] and [tag:polls] have been removed, taking out the legitimate uses with the bathwater.